# HTTP::Request->parse does not work as expected

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm trying to parse a HTTP request string with HTTP::Request->parse method,

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Referer: www.google.com
Cookies: A=B
```

(There's another "\r\n" at the end of it, but I can't append it without breaking the syntax highlighter ..)

The above string works when I send it with `nc www.google.com 80 < request`

Now I try to parse and send it throught LWP:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp qw/read_file/;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $request = HTTP::Request->parse (read_file ('/run/shm/request'));
print Dumper ($request);

my $r = $ua->request ($request);
if ($r->is_success)
{
    print $r->decoded_content;
}
else
{
    print $r->status_line;
}
```

And I get:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_headers' => bless( {}, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                 '_content' => '',
                 '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                 '_method' => 'GET',
                 '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = '/')}, 'URI::_generic' )
               }, 'HTTP::Request' );
400 URL must be absolute
```

So the parser is not working, it fails to parse both URI and Headers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program, especially when you are asking for help with it.

Comment: @Borodin I did, just removed it in the paste, and yes, no complain from Perl ;-)

Comment: It is best if you publish your *complete* code, or a reduced version that demonstrates the same misbehaviour. This particular problem was unlikely to have been caused by anything that `strict` or `warnings` would have uncovered, but more usually there would have been an additional and unnecessary to-and-fro asking you to add them and show the results.

Comment: Oh I get your meaning, I'll include them here and next time, thanks @Borodin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't like `File::Slurp`. It's mostly a replacement for the idiom

```
my $contents = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!;
  local $/;
  <$fh>;
};
```

or, if you pass the filename on the command line

```
my $contents = do {
  local $/;
  <>;
};
```

which is far from difficult to use, and makes it clear what is happening.

Here, `File::Slurp` is the cause of your problems because, when called in list context (and the parameters of a subroutine call apply list context) it returns a *list* of lines from the file instead of the whole file in a single scalar value.

Because `HTTP::Request->parse` looks only at the first parameter passed, it sees only the `GET` line, and produces a request with no headers.

You can fix it by writing

```
my $request = read_file ('/run/shm/request');
$request = HTTP::Request->parse($request);
```

or you may prefer

```
my $request = HTTP::Request->parse(scalar read_file ('/run/shm/request'));
```

But I would write something like

```
use autodie;

my $request = do {
  open my $fh, '<', '/run/shm/request';
  local $/;
  my $contents = <$fh>;
  HTTP::Request->parse($contents);
};
```

---

**Update**

By the way, a better way of viewing the HTTP message that `HTTP::Message` at al. has built for you is to use `print $message->as_string`. Using `Data::Dumper` shows a lot of irrelevant data and context that is used internally by the object, and there is no way of knowing what parts of it are relevant.

In the case of your program above, a corrected version that uses

```
print $request->as_string
```

results in this output

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Referer: www.google.com
Cookies: A=B
```

which is exactly what your input file contains, and is hopefully what you would expect.